# how to start qgis with --configpath option on windows

Tags: qgis, windows-7, command-line

how can I start QGIS on Windows 7 with the --configpath option?

I'm used to work with Linux where this procedure is very very simple (just write in a terminal **qgis --configpath**) with all the options.

Someone knows how to do the same thing on windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved directly editing the qgis.bat file (in C:\Program Files\QGIS\bin).

In the last line `start QGIS....` I just added the `--configpath` option.

But it works for all the other options too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to QGIS.

Create a shortcut to your qgis binary (right-click, drag somewhere with right mouse button, drop, select "create shortcut" from contextmenu. Right-click the shortcut, open properties, select the second tab (don't know how its called in english), then in the target field you can append parameters to the program call.

Comment: I tried but it ain't work for me..

Comment: For Windows, this will not work. The desktop shortcut and the file extension .qgs are bound to qgis.bat, which sets the necessary environment variables. Without them QGIS will not start properly.